# ERROR: Access test requires a Access database No connection established & Fatal error: Call to a member function Close() on a non-object in?

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access

I'm building an application with PHP and with existing MS Access.

So I'm trying to import an existing file from access but when I click the button Import I always got the error message

> Access test requires a Access database
>   C:/Server/htdocs/POA_iDB_Test/Uploads/TE00_Productlines.mdb No
>   connection established Fatal error: Call to a member function Close()
>   on a non-object in
>   C:\Server\htdocs\POA_iDB_Test\AdminArea\Perioden-Management\Access-Import\Productlines\import.php
>   on line 58

Here's my code

```
<?php
    /*  Letzte Änderung: 26.06.2013 durch fgraf
        */
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['usr_username']))
    {
        echo("Please login first !!");
        return;
    }
    $mydb = mysql_connect($_SESSION['db_server'], $_SESSION['db_username'], $_SESSION['db_password']);
    if (!$mydb) die (mysql.error()."<br>Cannot connect to $_SESSION[db_server] !!<br>Please Call the DB-Administration VISHAY Selb Germany");
    $db = mysql_select_db($_SESSION['db_name'], $mydb);
    if (!$db) die ('Cannot use database -'.$_SESSION['db_name'].'-' . mysql_error());

    $ini_array = parse_ini_file("../../../../Secure/config.ini", "Server");
    $pfad = $ini_array['Server']['access'];

    $YearStamp = $_GET['yearstamp'];

    if($_FILES['fdatei']['tmp_name'])
    {   
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fdatei']['tmp_name'], "../../../../Uploads/".$_SESSION['usr_vshid']."_".$_FILES['fdatei']['name']);
    }
    else
    {
        echo("Upload NOT successful !");
        return;
    }

    include('C:/Server/PHP/adodb/adodb.inc.php');
    ADOLoadCode('ado_access');

    $db = ADONewConnection("ado_access");
    $access = $pfad.$_SESSION['usr_vshid']."_".$_FILES['fdatei']['name'];
    $myDSN = 'PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE='.$access.';';

    if ($db->Connect($myDSN,"",""))
    {
        /*Removed by Lara Mae - January 12, 2017: for Access Import investigation and testing*/
        // $strSQL = "DELETE FROM tblproductlines WHERE YearStamp = '".$YearStamp."';";
        // mysql_query($strSQL, $mydb);

        $recordSET = $db->Execute("SELECT Line, Division, [Division Group], [Product Area], [VISHAY/BC], TM1Nr, TM1, [Division Group Seq], [Division Seq], [Line Seq], [SAMval] FROM Productlines;");
        $AnzahlRecords = 0;
        while (!$recordSET->EOF) 
        {
            /*Removed by Lara Mae - January 12, 2017: for Access Import investigation and testing*/
            //0=Line; 1=Division; 2=Division Group; 3=Product Area; 4=VISHAY/BC; 5=TM1Nr; 6=TM1; 7=Division Group Seq; 8=Division Seq; 9=Line Seq; 10=SAMval;
            // $strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblproductlines (Line, Division, DivisionGroup, ProductArea, VISHAYBC, TM1Nr, TM1, DivisionGroupSeq, DivisionSeq, LineSeq, SAMval, YearStamp) VALUES ('".addslashes($recordSET->fields[0])."','".addslashes($recordSET->fields[1])."','".addslashes($recordSET->fields[2])."','".addslashes($recordSET->fields[3])."','".addslashes($recordSET->fields[4])."','".addslashes($recordSET->fields[5])."','".addslashes($recordSET->fields[6])."',".(($recordSET->fields[7] == "") ? "NULL," : ("'".addslashes($recordSET->fields[7])."',")).(($recordSET->fields[8] == "") ? "NULL," : ("'".addslashes($recordSET->fields[8])."',")).(($recordSET->fields[9] == "") ? "NULL," : ("'".addslashes($recordSET->fields[9])."',"))."'".addslashes($recordSET->fields[10])."','".addslashes($YearStamp)."');";
            // mysql_query($strSQL, $mydb);
            $recordSET->MoveNext();
            $AnzahlRecords = $AnzahlRecords + 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo("ERROR: Access test requires a Access database ".$access."<br>".$db->ErrorMsg());
    }
    $recordSET->Close();
    $db->Close();

    unlink($access);
?>
```

Hope you can help me with this. I'm new with PHP and I don't know what seems to be the problem and what's causing the error. Do I need to install something for my application to work well, or is there a problem with my codes? Thanks.

Comment: comment code $recordSET->Close(); , i.e. line number 58 and see the effect. i think you only need to close the DB connection not the recordset object.  this is the errow because the method close is not supported or belongs to $recordSET. close method for this $recordSET is invalid.

Comment: @ShaileshSingh how about the error no established connection? what does that mean?

Comment: no connection with db while trying to close or manipulate i think. but you need to show your code with line number.

Comment: @ShaileshSingh so I think the problem is the ERROR: No established connection that's why it can't import the data. What are the possible solution for this. If that's the case. I'm sorry I ask too much question.